# Java [android] Activity, extern classes

Tags: java, android

Java newbie is here.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog dlg = builder.setMessage(messageText).create();
dlg.setOwnerActivity(this);
dlg.show();
```

^ this code works well in the main class, but when I try to make an extern one like this:

```
Messages myMessages = new Messages();
myMessages.SendAlert("Oh shi--!");
```

+

```
public class Messages extends Activity {
    public void SendAlert(String messageText) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog dlg = builder.setMessage(messageText).create();
        dlg.setOwnerActivity(this);
        dlg.show();
    }
}
```

^ it's not working at all.

What I can do with it? :-\

Comment: please list all your code and what you are trying to do so we have clue about what you want to do

Comment: What does "not working at all" means? Do you get a compile error or an exception?

Comment: Is that Activity currently in front, which has the method you are calling?

Comment: @Mr.Me what he already has done...

Comment: If the Messages activity is not "active" and you try to call a visible element there, using the class as a parent, it has cannot be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you cant create new activities like that.
Pass the creator activity into the Constructor of message instead of extending Activity.

```
public class Messages {
private Activity activity;
public Message(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void SendAlert(String messageText) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    AlertDialog dlg = builder.setMessage(messageText).create();
    dlg.setOwnerActivity(activity);
    dlg.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of constructing the `Message` with an `Activity` you should be creating it using a `Context`.

Comment: The dlg.setOwnerActivity(activity); requires activity and not context. Not sure why he uses it though, I have never used it. But if he removes that invocation then sure, Context is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a helper class.
The main idea is having static methods and passing the `Context` for every call.

For example:

```
public class AlertHelper {

  private AlertHelper() {
  }

  public static void sendAlert(Context ctx, String messageText) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    AlertDialog dlg = builder.setMessage(messageText).create();
    dlg.show();
  }
}
```